# Selenium Server with MbUnit not respecting Degree of Parallelism

Tags: selenium, functional-testing, selenium-grid, mbunit

I've got a question that I have researched but can't seem to find any help so I am going to ask here. Currently I am running a Selenium Server grid with 4 Firefox nodes the following is how I start the Grid and its nodes.

```
Hub: java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -role hub

Node:start java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/wd/hub -browser browserName=firefox,platform=WINDOWS,maxSession=1,ensureCleanSession=true,cleanupCycle=500 -port 4448
```

Note: I only listed one of the Firefox nodes cmd line to redunce redundancy.

In my Solution I have my Degree of Parallelism set to 4, which equates to one test per node.

I have the my Test Fixture classes marked like the following:

```
[Parallelizable][TestFixture(Order=2)]
public class TestSuiteA{ }
```

The problem: I have roughly 15 Test Fixture classes. When I attempt to execute a test run with all 15 fixtures, the Selenium Hub/MbUnit runner? tries to start all 15 Test fixtures at once instead of how I expected it to behave. Which causes the remaining 11 Test Fixtures to fail.

How I expected it to behave: I expected that once I executed a test run with all 15 test fixtures that the Selenium Grid/MbUnit?  would run all the test fixtures 4 test fixtures at a time. Then once a node becomes available it grabs one of the remaining 11 Test Fixtures and runs the tests associated with that Test Fixture. It then will repeate that process until all Test Fixtures have been run.

Does anyone have any idea why the Grid/MbUnit is not respecting the Degree of Parallelism?

Thanks in advance to all who reply!

-Travis

Edit: The DegreeOfParallelism attribute is located in my project's AssemblyInfo class. It appears as the follow:

```
[assembly: DegreeOfParallelism(4)]
```

Comment: `Degree Of Parallelism`??? Where? I don't see what code that relates to.

Comment: Arran, see my edit. The Degree of Parallelism attribute is located in the project's AssemblyInfo.cs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put the [Parallelizable]-attribute in front of every test case and not only in front of the class?